# Docker stack deploy is not updating existing containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am deploying 4 containers using `docker stack deploy` as below:

```sh
docker stack deploy --compose-file compose.yml --with-registry-auth myapp
```

For the first time, the containers are built using the latest image on the registry, no problem.

But when I push new images to the registry and run the commands again, the containers are not rebuilt using the latest images.

I am using the `latest` tag in my images. I know it is not the recommended way to do things, but for what I have read in the documentation, `docker stack deploy` if using the `latest` tag, will check for image sha with the registry, if it is different the containers will rebuild using latest images, but In my case, it's not happening. Am I missing something here?

I also get an error/warning when I run `docker stack deploy` once the stack is already up:

```
Updating service service_name (id: some_hash_value)
image docker.pkg.github.com/username/repository/image-name:latest could not be accessed on a registry to record
its digest. Each node will access docker.pkg.github.com/username/repository/image-name:latest independently,
possibly leading to different nodes running different
versions of the image.
```

Comment: Just curious, why is using the latest tag in images not the recommended way to do things? I've never come across this mentioned before?

Comment: @J.ScottElblein There is nothing wrong with it, but its not the recommended way. Check this out https://vsupalov.com/docker-latest-tag/

Comment: @J.ScottElblein also read this https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31357#issuecomment-430791141

Answer (score 0):

I encoutered the same error message when I started using a new docker registry. The new registry's SSL certificate was not considered secured by docker.

So I got this error until I added my new registry to the `insecure-registries` section of the `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

I've seen nobody mentionning this solution on this question or other similar ones, so I hoped this could help.